# Making isometric sprites out of a 3d model

Tags: rendering

I have created a 3d model in blender and I would like to render it as an isometric sprite..How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a bit more complicated to explain and to set up. You need to use an orthographic camera. And adjust its angle and position to some special values. This addon could help you with the steps. Use the game iso cam - http://www.reinerstilesets.de/anderes/blender-addons/create-isocam/

Comment: Some theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection